# Is there any tool where I can copy or replicate a file's indentation?

Tags: c, indentation

I want to replicate a particular file's indentation and not use autoindent. What I mean is, copy the indentation a 1 file to another file and add my own code in the 2nd file. But I need the 1st file's indentation in the 2nd file.

Comment: Questions like this are really off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Normally, you use and indentation tool configured the way you want both files to appear and use that. I don't know of a tool that identifies the indentation pattern from a source file.  It would be quite hard to write as it would have to deal with inconsistent indentation in the code that's present and infer what's wanted when the reference file contains no examples of a formatting issue.

Comment: indentation tool will indent a file but not copy 1 file's indentation into another.

Comment: Is there a tool to identify or extract a file's indentation?

Comment: `Gnu indent` will set a files indentation based upon a very flexible set of parameters you give it. Running it with the same options on 2 source files will essentially copy the indent (not really, but it will make them the same)

Comment: @user3356240: I said in my previous comment that I know of no tool to extract the indent style from a source file.